# Using two ng-repeats in one table and display it conditionally

Tags: angularjs

I'm using two ng-repeats to display all the details in one table. The two lists are noway related to each other. I want to display first list(customers and their Ids) in left side and second list(sales and it's Ids) in right side of the table.

The output should be like this.

```
    Customers   Id   Sales     Id
----------------------------------
    cust 1.1    1   site 2.1   4
    cust 1.2    2   site 2.2   5
    cust 1.3    3
    cust 1.4    7
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HftybLfTuNRRglY6v7Ia?p=preview)

Comment: You can create a single array as [{customers:"",id:"",sales:"",salesid:""},{customers:"",id:"",sales:"",salesid:""}] in your controller using these two arrays and repeat that in your template.

Comment: I'm also looking for answer.. Nikhilesh K V can you please edit plunker and make this work.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the solution for your question

[Solved Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NeSqSqxk1r7TAUV61SoT?p=preview)

```
 $scope.resList = $scope.customers.map(function(value, index) {
return {
    cust: value,
    sal: $scope.sales[index]
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Use table Following way

```
 <table>
  <tbody >
    <tr >
      <td valign='top'>
          <table>
            <tr><th>Customers</th> <th>Id</th> </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
              <td>{{customer.name}}</td><td>{{  customer.id}}</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
      <td valign='top'>
         <table>
          <tr><th>Sites</th> <th>Id</th></tr>  
           <tr ng-repeat="site in sales" >
              <td>{{site.name}}</td><td>{{  site.id}}</td>
           </tr>
         </table>
      </td>         
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Using Single array See  http://plnkr.co/edit/KOlX4RJ2pkNgfkD0Z0ft?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it may help you

```
<tbody>
   <tr  ng-repeat="customer in customers">          
      <td>{{customer.name}}</td><td>{{  customer.id}}</td>
      <td>{{sales[$index].name}}</td><td>{{sales[$index].id}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainController', function($scope){
  $scope.haha = "wow";
  $scope.customers = [
          {name: 'cust 1.1',id:"1"},
          {name: 'cust 1.2',id:"2"},
          {name: 'cust 1.3',id:"3"},
          {name: 'cust 1.4',id:"7"}
       
    ];
     $scope.sales = [
     
          {name: 'Site 2.1',id:"4"},
          {name: 'Site 2.2',id:"5"}
       
  ];
});

/* 

    output something like this.(customers)
    Customers   Id   Sales     Id
    ----------------------------------
    cust 1.1    1   site 2.1   4
    cust 1.2    2   site 2.2   5
    cust 1.3    3
    cust 1.4    7
  */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <table>
      <th>Customers</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Sites</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <tbody>
        <tr  ng-repeat="customer in customers">          
          <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
          <td>{{  customer.id}}</td>
          <td>{{sales[$index].name}}</td>
          <td>{{sales[$index].id}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` function, you can combine the two arrays into single one like below

```
$scope.resultArray = $scope.customers.map(function(value, index) {
    return {
        data1: value,
        data2: $scope.sales[index]
    }
});
```

and you can loop it using `ng-repeat`.

Here is the **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_7/5ya3xjoy/)**

Hope this helps :)